# Python Tkinter program for Status Bar

Tags: python

```
from Tkinter import *
class StatusBar(Frame):   
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.label = Label(self, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        self.label.pack(fill=X)        
    def set(self, format, *args):
        self.label.config(text=format % args)
        self.label.update_idletasks()
    def clear(self):
        self.label.config(text="")
        self.label.update_idletasks()
root = Tk()
root.update()
d =StatusBar(root)

d.pack()
mainloop()
```

Hi Friend.This is my code for Status bar.Even though i didn't get any error or warning. I had failed to obtain the status bar. But my Widget is getting opened with empty in it.Can any one please help me in this aspect.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's there; it's just very small because none of the widgets requested much space.
If you put some text in the Label, or gave `root` a geometry, it would be easier to see:

```
import Tkinter as tk
class StatusBar(tk.Frame):   
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.variable=tk.StringVar()        
        self.label=tk.Label(self, bd=1, relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W,
                           textvariable=self.variable,
                           font=('arial',16,'normal'))
        self.variable.set('Status Bar')
        self.label.pack(fill=tk.X)        
        self.pack()

root=tk.Tk()
d=StatusBar(root)
root.geometry('300x100')
root.mainloop()
```

---

By the way, to allow the text inside the label to change, use a `tk.StringVar`.
Calling `self.variable.set(...)` will change the label's text. And to clear it just call `self.variable.set('')`.